# setState delay in updating the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I was sending all the data of my form to an api, but I can't do it, this is my code

```
const handleSubmit = () => {

       setData({
                ...data,
                apellidoParterno: inputs.apellidoParterno,
                apellidoMaterno: inputs.apellidoMaterno,
                nombres: inputs.nombres,
                cargocontacto: inputs.cargocontacto,
                telèfonocontacto: inputs.telèfonocontacto,
                celularcontacto: inputs.celularcontacto,
                emailcontacto: inputs.emailcontacto,
            })
            onSubmitProveedor();
       
    }
```

the information is stored correctly in setData, but the problem is that it takes a little time to do that and that is why what I send to the api is nothing. This function "onSuibmitProveedor" is my function where I am sending the data

Comment: that's due to the fact that `setState` is asynchronous so the function `onSubmitProveedor` get called before the state changes. You can pass the data directly to the function to call the api.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `setState` is asynchronous; you can't read the updated `data` immediately.

You can either call `onSubmitProveedor` from an effect, e.g.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if(dataIsCompleteEnoughForSubmission(data)) onSubmitProveedor();
}, [data]);
```

or make `onSubmitProveedor` accept the data object and call it directly there:

```
const onSubmitProveedor = (data) => { ... };
const handleSubmit = () => {
  const fullData = {...data, apellido...};
  setData(fullData);
  onSubmitProveedor(fullData);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but I don't know if it's possible to use async or await in this case

Comment: I never said you need `async` or `await`, where did you get that from?

Comment: I am learning to program and as I saw that in some functions it is used to avoid this type of problem

Comment: Well, those keywords don't appear here at all, as you can see.